# Python with matplotlib

Tags: python

Is there a way to set up python 2.7.x + matplotlib on a tablet so that you can run simple standard python code? I would like to be able to run the same scripts I run on my Linux desktop,

Answer (score 1):

You can run python with SL4A but matplotlib is a graphical package so you are going to run into trouble there.